# Why won't Dragonrend work on Alduin?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am fighting the final boss, Alduin, in Sovngarde, and no matter how many times I use Dragonrend he won't land.

I'm not missing. The purple haze is there. He definitely has room to land. I can't defeat him with archery because I main two-handed weapons.

I just don't know what to do.

When I fought Odahviing the game bugged out. When he was released, the NPCs instantly started attacking him, so I couldn't progress and I couldn't kill him either. When I left the room and went back in he wasn't hostile anymore. I don't know what happened. Please help!

Comment: I'm about 90% sure you got downvotes due to poor formatting (capitalization, spelling, run-on sentences) and unnecessary swearing.  I cleaned it up for you. Still probably won't get upvotes, due to lack of research. Check the wiki I linked in my answer before coming here for Skyrim. If you can't figure it out from there, mention that you looked at it.

Answer (score 6):

You can't fight Alduin immediately after entering Sovngarde. You need to defeat Tsun and enter the Hall of Valor, where the heroes of Sovngarde will join you.

Together, you clear the haze and defeat Alduin.

See [the quest page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sovngarde_(Quest)) on The Elder Scrolls Wiki for additional details.